# How to apply my function to DataFrame column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've defined the following function:

```py
def clearString(myString):
    forbidden = r'/\:*?"<>|'
    for character in forbidden:
        if character in myString:
           myString = myString.replace(character,'')
    return myString
```

To remove unwanted characters in file names.
I have a data frame with book titles in a column and I'm trying to apply the function to all the strings inplace, to clear them, but have been unable to, I keep getting the DataFrame back with untouched data.

I've already tried the apply function, both in the column alone and the entire DataFrame, and none of that yields a positive result, be it assigning the DataFrame back to it self, as in:

```py
df = df.apply(clearString)
#Or even
df = clearString(df)
```

Or even defining a new one:

```py
df_new = df.apply(clearString)
#Or even
df_new = clearString(df)
```

Is there something wrong with my function maybe, like not properly handling DataFrames or something?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `axis` to 1?

Comment: I have indeed. Still keep getting the same original dataframe back, with no alterations. I have tried applying it to a single entry's value, in the format:
 `clearString(df.loc[x,y])`
And that works. Just can't iterate it over the entire DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` isn't working because, by default, it applies the given function to each column (and not to each element). In the given examples, `clearString` would receive a `Series` argument, not a `str`.

To apply a function to all the *elements* of a DataFrame, one can use the `applymap` method ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)).

Examples:

```
# if you wanna replace the old dataframe
df = df.applymap(clearString)

# if you wanna keep the old dataframe
new_df = df.applymap(clearString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map or even Apply and map combined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a single column you can try these approaches:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Title": ["one ", "two", "three", "four"]})
def clean(title):
    return title.upper()
df["Title"] = df["Title"].apply(lambda x: clean(x))
# OR 
df["Modified_Title"] = df["Title"].apply(lambda x: clean(x))
# OR 
df["Modified_Title1"] = df.apply(lambda x: clean(x["Title"]), axis=1)
# OR 
new_df = df.applymap(lambda x: clean(x))
```